# Как указать параметр с типом данных LPVOID

Tags: c++, winapi, request

Пытаюсь сделать запрос. `WinHttpSendRequest(Request, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 142, (LPVOID)("test"), 5, 0, 0);` При загрузки ответа выдаёт ошибку. Проблема проявляется только при указании параметров (LPVOID)("test"), 5.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение, нужно передавать ещё 1 параметр: `WinHttpSendRequest(Request, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 142, (LPVOID)("test"), 5, 5, 0);`(размер).

Comment: вы молодцы. постарались!